# How to upload image files to Object Storage in Bluemix using Java Liberty on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, object-storage

I have recently started working with **IBM's Bluemix** platform. I am trying to write a web application using Java EE on Eclipse that allows a user to upload an image that will be stored in the cloud using the **Object Storage service**.

Right now I have a Web App on Eclipse with Object Storage connected to it, but there is a lack of documentation (or I can't seem to find it) on how to access Object Storage from the code and utilize it to store files (specifically images) in the cloud.

I'm using an HTML form to upload the image file and a Servlet class to handle the form submission. Here's the form I'm using:

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/upload">
    Choose image to upload: <input type='file' name='newImage' /> <br> 
    <input type='submit' value='Upload Image' /> 
</form>
```

If anyone can offer help that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [Connecting to IBM Object Storage for Bluemix with Java](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connecting-to-ibm-object-storage-for-bluemix-with-java/). This tutorial shows how to use OpenStack4j and Java to connect with an Object Storage instance on Bluemix.

If you are going to push your application on Bluemix I suggest you to read also some basic concepts at  [Using Object Storage from a Bluemix app](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/objectstorge_usingobjectstorage.html#using-object-storage-from-bluemix-app).